# Add/Make New JDK the default JDK on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, flutter

I am Currently using JDK 16 on my mac book pro so i wanted to run a fluuter project which i bought from Codecanyon and i noticed an error which i looked up and the solution was the JDK version that i need to install jdk 8 in-other to run the project, so i downloaded the JDK8 and installed but when i run

> `Java -version`

i still get

> java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 16.0.2+7-67) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)

i have tried adding the file path to bash file by running

> touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile

and adding it to my path file like bellow

> export PATH="$PATH:/Users/bright/Development/flutter/bin" export
> PATH="$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

still when i run the

> `Java -version`
> i still see the version 16...

how do i set my Mac os to be seeing the JDK 8 or better still how to set it as the default JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few questions on stackoverflow like this.

In general to set java 1.8 as the shell enviroment try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

[How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos)

[set mac jdk version to 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779190/set-mac-jdk-version-to-1-8)